# Refraction vector not normalized

Tags: math, vector-graphics

How can I get the not-normalized output refracted vector, with an also not-normalized incident vector?

I'm following that formulas, work with normalized input, but if I pass not-normalized doesn't. Tried to divide the dot product by input vector length but also nothing.

[Wikipedia Snell's Law Vector form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law#Vector_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the dot product by the incident vector length, then your thetas will be correct.

After that, if you multiply **n** by the incident vector length, then your **v<sub>reflected</sub>** and **v<sub>refracted</sub>** vectors will be correct.